# Removing <div> with specific value

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have an issue with removing the  class

```html
<div>
  <div class="categoryname current-category">Category block</div>
  <div class="categoryname">Category block</div>
</div>
```

I am trying to display only block with class "categoryname current-category"

I try this CSS code:

```css
.categoryname{
    display:none;
}
.categoryname:first-child{
    display:block;
}
```

But that CSS code every time display first category, I am looking to only display block with "current-category" class,
Some pages have a situation that class "current-category" is on other block:

```html
<div>
  <div class="categoryname">Category block</div>
  <div class="categoryname current-category">Category block</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your css class name and html class not matched

Comment: Ops, check now pls I update

Comment: try .categoryname.current-category {display:block} or .categoryname:not(.current-category) {display:none}

Comment: Thanks, your second code work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When styling an element that contains more than one class you need to write the classnames without spaces

```css
.categoryname{
  display: none;
}
.categoryname.current-category{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="categoryname current-category">Category block</div>
  <div class="categoryname">Category block</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is related to the CSS Specificity.

*Specificity is by which browsers decide which CSS property values are the most relevant to an element and, therefore, will be applied.* - *MDN*

In your case, due to using pseudo-class, the specificity of the second CSS increases which will always apply by overriding the first CSS that you have written.

```
<element class="categoryname">: Selector Specificity: (0, 1, 0)
```

```
<element class="categoryname" :first-child>: Selector Specificity: (0, 2, 0)
```

So to fix your problem:

```
 .categoryname {
   display: none;
 }

 .categoryname .current-category {
   display: block; //Specificity: (0, 2, 0)
 }
```

For more details on the concept visit the official MDN Document: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity